# How to create a reusable component in D3 with an API that manipulates each instance of the component?

Tags: components, d3.js

Mike has an excellent article about writing [reusable components](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) in D3. The article describes a pattern of how to make components configurable, and how to apply the component to a selection.

The pattern allows a single component object to be reused with multiple selections by joining it to data; e.g.

```
var chart = myChart();

d3.select("div.chart")
  .data(data)
  .call(chart);
```

My component implementation looks like the following:

```
function myChart() {

    function my(selection) {
        selection.each(function(d, i) {

            // generate chart here
            // `d` is the data, `i` is the index, `this` is the element

            var state = false;

            var circle = d3.select(this).append("circle")
                .attr("r", "10")
                .style("fill", "#000")
                .on("click", toggleState);

            function toggleState() {
                // this function updates the current instance trapped by this closure
                (state = !state)
                    ? circle.style("fill", "#fff")
                    : circle.style("fill", "#000");
            }
        });
    }

    my.toggleState(i) {
        // How do I access the `i`th instance of the component here?
    }

    return my;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to allow the caller to manipulate an instance of this component given its index. For example, if the selector `div.chart` above returns a selection that has two elements, I'd like to call `chart.toggleState(1)` and have it update the 2nd div in the selection.

Just so I don't confuse anyone why I'm trying to do this, the caller needs to synchronize two types of components together. Imagine I have a component that is represented by a circle and another component that is represented by a rectangle. The two components must be independent and not tied to each other. I need to be able to create 4 circles and 4 rectangles, and when I click a rectangle, I'd like to be able to update the corresponding circle based on index order. I have already figured out how to raise events (d3.dispatch) from a component and provide the current index as a parameter in the event, but I haven't figured out how to call into a specific instance of a component given its index.

Comment: It sounds to me as if the way to do it would be to select only the element you need to update and then call the component. Anything else would violate the encapsulation you achieve through this component pattern.

Comment: I recently finished work an on open source reusable component, based on Mikes article. https://timebandit.github.io/graphSub

Comment: Thanks a lot @timebandit! Your example is spot on! Wish it would show up in Google results when searching for "how to create d3 component"

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to give every component the same class. Then when you call `chart.toggleState(1)` you can do `d3.selectAll('.component').each(function(d, i) { if (i == index) doWhatever; });`

Answer (score 0):

The data for a particular selection is in selection[0]. You can select the ith element and set an attribute thusly:

```
var i = 3
d3.select(mySelection[0][i]).attr("fill","#fff")
```

If you know the i, you could write toggleState thus:

```
function toggleState(i) {
    var toggle_me = d3.select(circles[0][i])
    var state = !(toggle_me.attr("fill") == "#fff")
    toggle_me.attr("fill", (state ? "#fff": "#000"))
}
```

If you didn't know the i, you could write toggleState thus:

```
function toggleState() {
    var toggle_me = d3.select(this)
    var i = circles[0].findIndex(function(d) {
        return d == toggle_me[0][0]
    })
    if (i !== -1) {
        var state = !(toggle_me.attr("fill") == "#fff")
        toggle_me.attr("fill", (state ? "#fff": "#000"))
      // Do additional functions with i here
      //var triange = d3.select(triangles[0][i])
      //...
    }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fd7fyeoq/

For the same answer in a different context see:
[d3js : How to select nth element of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278107/d3js-how-to-select-nth-element-of-a-group)