# d3js : How to select nth element of a group?

Tags: d3.js

I create a group with 9 elements (circles) such as:

```
// JS
var data=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var circles = svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupOfCircles")
    .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return d*20;})
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return d*10;})
        .attr("r" , function(d){ return d;})
        .attr("fill","green");
```

[image]

```
//xml
<svg>
    <g id="groupOfCircles">
        <circle cx="20" cy="10" r="1" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="2" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="60" cy="30" r="3" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="4" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="5" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="120" cy="60" r="6" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="140" cy="70" r="7" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="160" cy="80" r="8" fill="green"></circle>
        <circle cx="180" cy="90" r="9" fill="green"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

But **How to select the nth element (i.e : the 3rd circle) of the group `groupOfCircles` while not knowing the circles' id or attributes values ?**

I will later on loop over all elements via a for loop, and color each for one second.

---

Note: I tried things such as :

```
  circles[3].attr("fill","red") // not working
  d3.select("#groupOfCircles:nth-child(3)").attr("fill","red")  // not working
  ..
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The selector needs to be `circle:nth-child(3)` -- the `child` means that the element is the nth child, not to select the nth child of the element (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)).

You could also use:

```js
    // JS
    var data=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ];
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
    var circles = svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupOfCircles")
        .selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d){ return d*20;})
            .attr("cy", function(d){ return d*10;})
            .attr("r" , function(d){ return d;})
            .attr("fill","green");
    
    d3.select("circle:nth-child(3)").attr("fill","red"); // <== CSS selector (DOM)
    d3.select(circles[0][4]).attr("fill","blue"); // <== D3 selector (node)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How about for d3 v4? You can't do `circles[0][4]` anymore.

Comment: The internals have changed, but you can still do this: `circles._groups[0][4]`.

Answer (score 9):

d3 **v4** now supports using *selection*.nodes() to return an array of all elements of this *selection*. Then, we can change the attributes of *n*th element by d3.select(*selection*.nodes()[*n*]).attr(*something*)

```js
// JS
var data=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var circles = svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupOfCircles")
    .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return d*20;})
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return d*10;})
        .attr("r" , function(d){ return d;})
        .attr("fill","green");

circleElements = circles.nodes(); // <== Get all circle elements
d3.select(circleElements[6]).attr("fill","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: reselecting from nodes might be not efficient, why shouldn't d3 have jquery equivalent of .eq()

Answer (score 3):

You can also use your circles array to set the element's attribute:

```
d3.select(circles[3]).attr("fill","red");
```

```js
// JS
var data=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var circles = svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupOfCircles")
    .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return d*20;})
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return d*10;})
        .attr("r" , function(d){ return d;})
        .attr("fill","green");

var group = document.querySelector('#groupOfCircles');
var circleNodes = group.getElementsByTagName('circle');
d3.select(circleNodes[3]).attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, but it doesn't seems to work on my fiddle. Can you provide one ?

Comment: This won't work because D3 selections aren't really arrays, it would need to be something like `circles[0][3].attr(...)` or `d3.select(circles[0][3].node()).attr(...)`.

Comment: @Peter Ah ok, your `circles` isn't a D3 selection but an array of the nodes. In that case it works fine, I just assumed that it was a D3 selection like in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in d3 logic, the anonymous function always has an index parameter aside the data:

```
my_selection.attr("fill",function(d,i) {return i%3==0?"red":"green";});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/risto/os5fj9m6/

Comment: This is the way I usually go for, but I though it to be a bit excessive to redraw all the selection when you actually want to change a single element.

Comment: The color is set only one time, when the circles are drawn. You certainly don't  have to reselect everything. whereas your original approach does a reselect.

Comment: I actually will 1. draw the circle in green ; 2. make an update loop to recolor the target circle for 1 second. If I reuse your `return i===3?"red":"green"` inside my for loop, at each cycle I will redraw all circles, and color in red the one respecting the condition. (If I understand d3 well)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option by using a function as the selector.

```
    circles.select(function (d,i) { return (i==3) ?  this : null;})
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

If the selector is a function it gets the datum (d) and the iterator (i) as parameter. It then returns either the object (this) if selected or null if not selected.